# Java reflection derived class

Tags: java, reflection

This is my scenario "I have a abstract class. There are many derived classed extending this abstract class with the use of annotations. In addition, I have a method of abstract class, that was reflected all notations in one particular derived class".

```
// Here's a definition of annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface SampleAnnotation {
   int sample();
}

public abstract class A { 

 // Here's a method to reflect all annotations
 // in particular derived class like B or C
 @Override
 public void foo() {

 }}

public class B extends A {
  @SampleAnnotation (sample = 1)
  public void step1() {}

  @SampleAnnotation (sample = 2)
  public void step2() {}

}

public class C extends A {
  @SampleAnnotation (sample = 1)
  public void step1() {}

  @Sample (stage = 2)
  public void step2() {}
}
```

How can I use java reflection to reflect all the annotations in specific derived class like B or C ?

Comment: If you could give an example *in code* it would make it easier to make sure that we understand the question correctly.

Comment: some sort of code always help other to understand your point/problem more correctly

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you have in mind is this [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library.

> Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:
>
> - get all subtypes of some type
> - get all types/methods/fields annotated with some annotation, w/o annotation parameters matching
> - get all resources matching matching a regular expression

Answer (score 1):

It depends:

1. Do you want to get all method annotations of **a concrete class**
2. Do you want to get all method annotations of **all concrete classes**

The first one can be achieved with a method implementation of `foo` like this:

```
public void foo() {
     for (Method method : this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
          for (Annotation a : method.getAnnotations()) {
              // do something with a
          }
     }
}
```

Then you can invoke `foo` from your concrete class,  for instance:

`new B().foo();`

For the second case you will need to do class path scanning as *Peter Lawrey* has pointed out.